# How to write a unit test for a REST login web service using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, unit-testing, spring-boot

I am developing one application using spring boot. I would like to unit test my Rest service login(), my service works well (I used postman). please take a look at what I tried for my unite test.
for example when I type a correct username and password I got a token as a return value:

[image]

and when I enter a false username and password I got this:

[image]

these is my architecture of my app:

```
app
 |
src/main/java
 |--DemoApplication.java
 |--dao.package
         |--UserRepository.java
 |--jwt.package
         |--UserController.java
src/test/java
 |--jwt.package.test
         |--UserControllerTest.java
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping("login")
    public LoginResponse login(@RequestBody final UserLogin login)
        throws ServletException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException {

        User user = userRepository.findByUsernameAndPassword(login.username,
            login.password);

        if (user == null)
            throw new ServletException("Invalid login");

        StringBuilder roles = new StringBuilder();
        user.getRoles()
            .forEach(role -> roles.append(role.getName()).append(","));
        return new LoginResponse(Jwts.builder().setSubject(login.username)
            .claim("roles", roles).setIssuedAt(new Date())
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "accenture".getBytes("UTF-8"))
            .compact());
    }

    private static class UserLogin {

        public String username;

        public String password;
    }

    private static class LoginResponse {

        public String token;

        public LoginResponse(final String token) {
            this.token = token;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to test my login web service but still not correct. Anyone could help me please to unit test my login service

**UserControllerTest.java:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = UserController.class, secure = false)
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    User mockUser = new User("test", "test");

    String exampleUserJson = "{\"username\":\"toto\",\"password\":\"toto\"}";


    @Test
    public void loginTest() throws Exception {


        User mockUser = new User("test", "test");

    Mockito.when(
            userRepository.findByUsernameAndPassword(Mockito.anyString(),
                Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockUser);

    // Send course as body to /students/Student1/courses
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .post("/user/login")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(exampleUserJson)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

    MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();

    assertEquals(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), response.getStatus());

    assertEquals("http://localhost/user/login",
            response.getHeader(HttpHeaders.LOCATION));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all understand how spring security works.**

if you do not provide any configuration it will ask for authentication for every thing.

if you want to test authentication then what you just need to do is call any secure api with username and password like below,

```
 curl -v http://localhost:9090/mynet/ -u admin:admin12344 -c D:\cookies.txt -H "Accept: application/json"
```

**Success senario** : In above example i have called secured endpoint and get a cookie in response with  HTTP/1.1 200 if authentication is success which you can use for further call as below,

```
curl -v http://localhost:9090/mynet/customers -b D:\cookies.txt
```

**Failure scenario** : We get  HTTP/1.1 401 with json

```
{"timestamp":1496645081468,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken","path":"/mynet/"}
```

**Note : I know you need to check above call using java code instead curl. I have used this just to explain concept.**